# gltf DOM events in a-frame

Tags: events, model, aframe, gltf

I am unable to capture "click" event in my gltf model in a-frame. Here is the code. A-frame documentation shows only two events are supported. Namely "model-loaded" and "model-error". How do we go about supporting other events such as "Click" and "mouseenter"?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('material-displacement', {
  /**

  */
  init: function () {
    this.material  = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: "green"});
    this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => { this.update(); });
  },

  /**
   * Apply the material to the current entity.
   */
  update: function () {
    const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    if (mesh) {
      mesh.traverse((node) => {
        if (node.isMesh) node.material = this.material;
      });
    }
  },   

});
```

Comment: Click events are triggered by the [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html), not the model itself, but they still apply regardless of the model format.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Which means I need to register the cursor-listener component and that would handle the click and other mouse events?

Comment: as long as you have a `cursor` component set up correctly, it will fire the events. Then you can use cursor-listener to handle those events, or [trigger animations without any extra  components](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html#adding-visual-feedback).

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I tried that but sadly could not get it to work. Kindly see my code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032056/gltf-cursor-listener-click-event-in-a-frame

Answer (score 0):

You implement them just as you would think you do. Instead of Having the Event Listener listen to a model-loaded event you make it listen to a click or mouseenter event.

So change this line

```
this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => { this.update(); });
```

to this line

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', () => { this.update(); });
```