# gltf cursor-listener click event in A-frame

Tags: click, cursor, aframe, gltf

I am unable to figure out why cursor-listener works fine for all the entities except for my gltf model.

Here is my html

```
<div id="myEmbeddedScene">
  <a-scene embedded="">
    <a-assets>
          <a-asset-item id="ducks" src="../images/test.glb"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <a-box cursor-listener color="#CCC" width="3" depth="3" height="0.1" position="0 0 -2"></a-box>

    <a-entity cursor-listener id="duck" gltf-model="#ducks" position="0 0.1 -2" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-entity>

    <a-camera>
      <a-cursor></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>

  </a-scene>
</div>
```

and here goes the cursor-listener component from a-frame

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
    init: function () {
            this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            console.log('I was clicked');               
        });
  }
});
```

The console log occurs just fine for the box entity but not for the gltf model. Please could someone offer their advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into the [issue described here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2980): After a model loads, the raycaster used to detect clicks needs to be refreshed, so that it knows about the model.

We have a [more robust solution on the way](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3070) for A-Frame 0.8.0, but in the meantime you can work around the problem with something like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('raycaster-autorefresh', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', function () {
      var cursorEl = el.querySelector('[raycaster]');
      cursorEl.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
    });
  }
});
```

You would then need to add the `raycaster-autorefresh` to your scene element. Here is a [Codepen showing the solution](https://codepen.io/donmccurdy/pen/mqJpVa?editors=1000#).

Comment: @Akki619 if `cursorEl` is null, then you don't have a raycaster or cursor in your scene. Please open a new question with some code if you're having trouble.

Comment: sure will do it in next 5 min

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614093/aframe-glft-click-event please see above question for issue i am facing