# How to add js onclick event to aframe animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, onclick, aframe

I have a spaceship model that I would like to animate taking off. I would like it to be so that the animation would activate once I click on the spaceship with my cursor. I have the animation working using  but I would like it to activate upon a cursor click event. Below is my HTML and where I got stuck with the JS

```
<a-entity id="spaceship" cursor-animator gltf-model="models/spaceship.gltf" position="-20 -0.855 -5.259" scale="2 2 2" rotation="0 180 0">
  <a-animation attribute="position" from="-20 0 -5" to="-20 0 -25" dur="10000"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="position" from="-20 0 -25" to="-20 1000 -200" delay="9000" dur="9000"></a-animation>
</a-entity>


// Component to activate spaceship animation on click
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-animator', {
init: function () {
this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    //Code
  console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding the 'begin' attribute to the animation tags:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/animations.html#begin

```
<a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="spaceship" cursor-animator gltf-model="models/spaceship.gltf" position="-20 -0.855 -5.259" scale="2 2 2" rotation="0 180 0">
  <a-animation begin="click" attribute="position" from="-20 0 -5" to="-20 0 -25" dur="10000"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="click" attribute="position" from="-20 0 -25" to="-20 1000 -200" delay="9000" dur="9000"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Tried this still doesn't work,My main problem is creating the JavaScript function to trigger the animation

Comment: Here's a basic box example with the mouse click, one thing that's not obvious is that you need to add the cursor attribute to the camera, perhaps that could be of help (updated answer to reflect that). https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-click-animate

Comment: Your solution works it just doesn't seem to work with my gltf model. With the box primitive onclick animation works perfectly. I switch in the model it just fails. I think this has to do with Aframe itself. Thanks

Comment: I see, perhaps this one could be of help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032056/gltf-cursor-listener-click-event-in-a-frame

Comment: Perfect that solved my problem, I will mark this question as a duplicate