# aframe glft click event

Tags: angularjs, aframe

I am trying to catch click event for glft model in a scene. Scene code below.

```
<a-scene raycaster-autorefresh> 
    <a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="store_homeModel" src="app/home/store_models/store_model.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     <a-asset-item id="shampoo" src="app/home/product_models/Ayush Shampoo.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     <a-asset-item id="soap" src="app/home/product_models/Ayush Soap.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     <a-asset-item id="facewash" src="app/home/product_models/Citra Pearl face wash.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>


    <a-gltf-model src="#store_homeModel"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-gltf-model src="#shampoo" open-desc"></a-gltf-model>

</a-scene>
```

and component code I have. But click event is not getting catch and i am not able to see console log...

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('raycaster-autorefresh', {
  init: function () {
    // This will be called after the entity has properly attached and loaded.
    console.log('I am readyyyyy!');
  }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('open-desc', {  
    init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;      
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiii");           
        });
    },

});
```

Comment: What version of A-Frame are you using? 0.8.0 may have some bug fixes you need. Does `I am readyyyy` get printed?

Comment: yes I am ready gets printed....and using 0.8.0 only

Comment: You must use a `cursor` for click events to be created. See [cursor docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html)

Comment: got it thanks @DonMcCurdy. request you to post it as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that `a-frame` renders the whole view on a `<canvas>`, so you can't just use your mouse to click on any element inside the `<a-scene>`.

If you want a simple gaze based cursor, you need to attach a cursor to the camera:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-cursor></a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

---

If You want to use the mouse, use the cursor component in the `<a-scene>`:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin:mouse">
```

---

If you want to use vive / oculus controllers, you should try `laser-controls`.

More details about properties and events regarding the cursor can be found in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html).